# Using Google App Engine for static files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to serve the static data for my website from Google App Engine.

How do I configure GAE to serve static content?

Comment: I'd be wary of Google cracking down on this at some point.

Comment: @ceejayoz Why? Google has clearly-stated limits on static, as well as dynamic file access. Using GAE as a static file-storage/caching solution doesn't go against their expectations.

Comment: It's Google **App** Engine, not Google CDN Engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation on how to get GAE to serve static content is here: [Using Static Files](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html).

It's rather simple, you just define a static directory in your `app.yaml` file.

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

Answer (score 1):

You want all files served as static so should use this:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_dir: /
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote article step by step to setup GAE to host static files. http://www.ivankristianto.com/internet/tools/setup-your-google-app-engine-application-to-use-your-own-domain/1656/
That may interest you.